# how to open url on page load from the hyperlinks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have many hyper-links in a `table tr`  so i want it to open whenever I refresh/load this page.

How do I do this?
I checked in `<a href` there is no `OnLoad` option for calling any javascript function.
please help me..

I have table like:

```
<table> 
  <tr class="oddrow">
    <td>Google</td> 
    <td> 
      <a style="color: blue;" href="www.google.com"> my website link 1</a>
    </td> 
  </tr> 

  <tr class="oddrow">
    <td>Stackoverflow</td> 
    <td> 
      <a style="color: blue;" href="www.stackoverflow.com"> my website link 2</a>
    </td> 
  </tr>  

  <tr class="oddrow">
    <td>Yahoo</td> 
    <td> 
      <a style="color: blue;" href="www.yahoo.com"> my website link 2</a>
    </td> 
  </tr> 
</table>
```

Comment: Are you saying that when you load the page with <table> on it, you want it to automatically open up the URL(s) on this table? In any particular order?

Comment: @JWarner112 yes, i want same thing. when page load just open all url inside the `table tr` to new tabs

Comment: @aldanux i checked but there is `onload` option in `a href`

Comment: try `window.location.href = "www.page.com"`

Comment: From a usability standpoint, this sounds like it's going to be really annoying. Are you going to use this in a live site, or is this for the sake of learning jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned `jQuery` on your tags, so:

```
$(function () {
    $("table tr td a").each(function (idx, el) {
        // As your markup is invalid - href to an external page not
        // starting with http://, let's add it here.
        // Otherwise the browser will interpret it as an anchor.
        var w = window.open("http://" + $(el).attr("href"));
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kqLSY/3/

Most of the browsers will block this as it's an attempt to open popups.

Comment: Two problem with your code:  #1. its not opening in new tab, its opening in popup                        #2. Its not opening the www.google.com , its opening the combination of  `current url/www.google.com`

Comment: The second problem is because your `href` doesn't start with `http://` which the browser identifies as an `anchor` instead. To open or not on tabs, it's a browser setting. On mine it's open on tabs. I've updated the answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

can you please check this code [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/malvaniya_shakti/KPxQy/6/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( "table tr a" ).each(function( index ) {
 window.open(this.href);
});
});
```

Comment: Two problem with your code:  #1. its not opening in new tab, its opening in popup                        #2. Its not opening the www.google.com , its opening the combination of  `current url/www.google.com`

Comment: can you please check now